# How to populate tableView custom cell in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableview

I am loading news from the server in to the tableView. Now I want to make a custom cell with headline, image and excerpt.
I made a custom class for the cell and I gave the cell custom identifier.
I put two labels (one for headline and one for excerpt).
Now I just want to display headline in the first label and excerpt in the second label.

```
       @IBOutlet weak var headline: UILabel!

       @IBOutlet weak var excerpt: UILabel!

//Custom struct for the data
struct News {
    let title : String
    let text : String
    let link : String
    let imgUrl : String

    init(dictionary: [String:String]) {
        self.title = dictionary["title"] ?? ""
        self.text = dictionary["text"] ?? ""
        self.link = dictionary["link"] ?? ""
        self.imgUrl = dictionary["imgUrl"] ?? ""
    }
}

//Array which holds the news
var newsData = [News]()

// Download the news
func downloadData() {
    Alamofire.request("https://api.sis.kemoke.net/news").responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request)  // original URL request
        print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
        print(response.data)     // server data
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

        //Optional binding to handle exceptions
        self.newsData.removeAll() // clean the data source array
        if let json = response.result.value as? [[String:String]] {
            for news in json {
                self.newsData.append(News(dictionary: news))
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

And in the following method I display the data in the cell

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt     indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let news = newsData[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = news.title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = news.text
    return cell
 }
```

Comment: Whats the name of your custom class? You should cast the Cell as your custom toy and you will be able to do what you want!

Comment: For Example I have a table view cell custom class Called NewsCell So I do:  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newsCell") as? NewsCell

Comment: Could you please provide more information? Should I add those labels in my custom class "newsCellTableViewCell"?

Comment: Change this line: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) To This: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? newsCellTableViewCell

Comment: @Mago Nicolas Palacios

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass from `UITableViewCell` f.e. `NewsCell`.

connect your outlets

```
@IBOutlet weak var headline: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var excerpt: UILabel!
```

to `NewsCell`. In your   `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt     indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {`

function cast the cell like this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? NewsCell
```

and set your properties.

Make sure you set the class of the storyboard prototype cell as NewsCell.